# How to splitting records based white spaces when different lines have spaces at different positions

Tags: java, regex

I have a file with records as below and I am trying to split the records in it based on white spaces and convert them into comma.

file:

```
a 3w 12 98 header P6124
e 4t 2  100 header I803
c 12L 11 437       M12


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/myfile.txt"));
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
System.out.println(line);
line = reader.readLine();
String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s+")
```

If the data is separated by multiple white spaces, I usually go for regex replace -> `split('\\s+')` or `split(" +")`.
But in the above case, I have a record `c` which doesn't have the data `header`. Hence the regex "\s+" or " +" will just skip that record and I will get an empty space as `c,12L,11,437,M12` instead of `c,12L,11,437,,M12`

How do I properly split the lines based on any delimiter in this case so that I get data in the below format:

```
a,3w,12,98,header,P6124
e,4t,2,100,header,I803
c,12L,11,437,,M12
```

Could anyone let me know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Is there a rule for a maximum number of allowed consecutive spaces?

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter isn't the tab character? Have you tried line.split("\t", -1)?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try using a more complicated approach, using a complex regex in order to match exatcly six fields for each line and handling explicitly the case of a missing value for the fifth one.
I rewrote your example adding some *console log* in order to clarify my suggestion:

```
public class RegexTest {
    private static final String Input = "a 3w 12 98 header P6124\n" +
            "e 4t 2  100 header I803\n" +
            "c 12L 11 437       M12";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(Input));
        String line = null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)? +([^ ]+)$");

        do {
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line != null) {
                String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s+");
                System.out.println(splitLine.length);

                System.out.println("Line: " + line);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                System.out.println("matches: " + matcher.matches());
                System.out.println("groups: " + matcher.groupCount());
                for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("   Group %d has value '%s'\n", i, matcher.group(i));
                }
            }
        } while (line != null);
    }
}
```

The key is that the pattern used to match each line requires a sequence of six fields:

- for each field, the value is described as `[^ ]+`
- separators between fields are described as `+`
- the value of the fifth (*nullable*) field is described as `[^ ]+?`
- each value is captured as a group using parentheses: `( ... )`
- start (`^`) and end (`$`) of each line are marked explicitly

Then, each line is matched against the given pattern, obtaining six groups: you can access each group using `matcher.group(index)`, where `index` is *1-based* because `group(0)` returns the full match.

This is a more complex approach but I think it can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put a limit on the number of whitespace chars that may be used to split the input.

In the case of your example data, a maximum of 5 works:

```
String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s{1,5}");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/Z09cLi) (of this code working as desired).

Comment: @Nexevis no, it works perfectly with the example data provided (see link to live demo). Recall that `Arrays.toString()` adds a space after every comma; perhaps you have misinterpreted that space as being the element itself?

Comment: If I use this and make a String out of it as, String s = line.split("\\s{1,5}").mkString(",") I see it works fine when there is no value in that particular place. But it is also resulting in wrong output sometimes like: 
e,4t,2,100,header,,,I803 -> It is giving three commas after the digit.

Answer (score -1):

Are you just trying to switch your delimiters from spaces to commas?

In that case:
`cat myFile.txt | sed 's/   */  /g' | sed 's/ /,/g'`

*edit: added a stage to strip out lists of more than two spaces, replacing them with just the two spaces needed to retain the double comma.

Comment: That would result in e.g. `c,12L,11,437,,,,,,,M12`, not the requested `c,12L,11,437,,M12`

Comment: Oh right, I'm dumb. However, this should do the trick? cat myFile.txt | sed 's/   */  /g' | sed 's/ /,/g' (so match for 2+ spaces and replace them with two, then replace all spaces with ,)

Comment: Then `e_4t_2__100_header_I803` (using `_` to show spaces correctly) won't become `e,4t,2,100,header,I803`. You should read the question, and look at the examples.